# How to get Discord on RPi 4?

Tags: pi-4, software-recommendation

I've been trying to download Discord on my RPi 4 but I need to download all this fancy software. Does anyone know how to install Discord with only 1 or 2 software downloads? (Or none.)

Comment: what is `all this fancy software` ... is that same as `stuff`? .... your question is not about Raspberry Pi ... it is a linux question

Comment: 1. I'm trying to download Discord *on RPi 4*. 2. This *fancy software* is stuff like ```snapd``` or ```Pi Apps```.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpacingBat's version it is just the web app in electron.
https://github.com/SpacingBat3/WebCord/releases
The only other option is to build it yourself or use it in a browser.

Comment: I will try when I have the time but I hope it works!